# Parse XML using SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, xml, xquery, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to clean up some SQL code. Currently I have an XML like:

```sql
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<PubmedArticleSet>
  <PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">           
      <ArticleIdList>           
        <ArticleId IdType="pii">0092-8674(92)90516-F</ArticleId>
        <ArticleId IdType="pubmed">1423608</ArticleId>
        <ArticleId IdType="doi">10.1016/0092-8674(92)90516-f</ArticleId>
      </ArticleIdList>
    </PubmedData>
  </PubmedArticle>
</PubmedArticleSet>'
```

And I need to get the value of the `ArticleId` with the attribute of

```xml
    IdType ="pubmed"
```

I would like something like and `XQUERY` method that could:

```sql
DECLARE @PMID NVARCHAR(15)
SET @PMID =  @xml.value('(//PubmedData/ArticleIdList/ArticleId/@IdType)[1]', 'varchar(15)' )
```

But that pulls the IdType "pii" of the first node. And

```sql
SET @PMID =  @xml.value('(//PubmedData/ArticleIdList/ArticleId/@IdType = "pubmed")[1]', 'varchar(15)' )
```

Brings back true.

Is there a way to filter based upon "pubmed" and then get the number 1423608?  So `@PMID` would then be equal to 1423608.

Comment: Your xpath does not seem to match the XML, but if it does, then it should be `'(//PubmedData/ArticleIdList/ArticleId[@IdType="pubmed"])[1]'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provided XML is not well-formed. There are several tags missing, hope this is corrected here:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<PubmedArticleSet>
  <PubmedArticle>
  <PubmedData>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">           
      <ArticleIdList>           
        <ArticleId IdType="pii">0092-8674(92)90516-F</ArticleId>
        <ArticleId IdType="pubmed">1423608</ArticleId>
        <ArticleId IdType="doi">10.1016/0092-8674(92)90516-f</ArticleId>
      </ArticleIdList>
      </MedlineCitation>
    </PubmedData>
  </PubmedArticle>
</PubmedArticleSet>';

DECLARE @IdToFind VARCHAR(100)='pubmed';

SELECT @xml.value('(/PubmedArticleSet
                    /PubmedArticle
                    /PubmedData
                    /MedlineCitation
                    /ArticleIdList
                    /ArticleId[@IdType=sql:variable("@IdToFind")]
                    /text())[1]','int');
```

The idea in short:

- We can use variable to get this a bit more generic.
- We dive into the XML, down to the `<ArticleIdList>` and
- find the one `<ArticleId>` where the attribute `IdType` equals the given value.
- From there we return the `text()`.

You would get the same with a simple *deep search* too:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(//ArticleId[@IdType=sql:variable("@IdToFind")]/text())[1]','int');
```

But the general advise is: Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Works Great-- Sorry about the poor formatting of the xml.  I pulled out a couple of tags because the xml is very long and my sample code still had them in it